# GSON serialize of SNSEvent resulting in lower case fields which lambda expects Capitalize words

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sns

I have a lambda function which takes SNSEvent(http://javadox.com/com.amazonaws/aws-lambda-java-events/1.1.0/com/amazonaws/services/lambda/runtime/events/SNSEvent.html) as the input and then works on that. For writing the some integration test cases, I wanted to call this lambda with the SNSEvent serialized using using lambda.invoke in which the message would be string.

So, for that, I was doing GSON.toJson([object of SNSEvent type]) and from this, I was getting a string. But the problem is, when I am using this string the invoke the lambda, I am getting an exception that deserialization of this string is failing.

Eg. GSON.toJson is deserializing to :

```
{
  "records": [
    {
      "eventSource": "aws:sns",
      "eventVersion": "1.0",
      "eventSubscriptionArn": "arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:{{{accountId}}}:ExampleTopic",
      "sns": {
        "type": "Notification",
        "messageId": "95df01b4-ee98-5cb9-9903-4c221d41eb5e",
        "topicArn": "arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:{{accountId}}:ExampleTopic",
        "subject": "example subject",
        "message": "example message",
        "timestamp": "1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
        "signatureVersion": "1",
        "signature": "EXAMPLE",
        "signingCertUrl": "EXAMPLE",
        "unsubscribeUrl": "EXAMPLE",
        "messageAttributes": {
          "test": {
            "type": "String",
            "value": "TestString"
          },
          "testBinary": {
            "type": "Binary",
            "value": "TestBinary"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

while, the actual, it wants is (with capital letters):

```
{
  "Records": [
    {
      "EventSource": "aws:sns",
      "EventVersion": "1.0",
      "EventSubscriptionArn": "arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:{{{accountId}}}:ExampleTopic",
      "Sns": {
        "Type": "Notification",
        "MessageId": "95df01b4-ee98-5cb9-9903-4c221d41eb5e",
        "TopicArn": "arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:{{accountId}}:ExampleTopic",
        "Subject": "example subject",
        "Message": "example message",
        "Timestamp": "1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
        "SignatureVersion": "1",
        "Signature": "EXAMPLE",
        "SigningCertUrl": "EXAMPLE",
        "UnsubscribeUrl": "EXAMPLE",
        "MessageAttributes": {
          "Test": {
            "Type": "String",
            "Value": "TestString"
          },
          "TestBinary": {
            "Type": "Binary",
            "Value": "TestBinary"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Any idea why is it so? And how can I fix it? Should I use some other object instead of SNSEvent while invoking the lambda.